# What's the diffetence between "thief" and "cheater"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Could you please help me to choose the right variant here.
Is the word "**cheater**" correct here?

> When Brenda later gives, shares, or trades her music files free over
>   the Internet, she is also an uploader. She considers herself an active
>   music uploader, but the music industry considers her a _____.
>
> А) thief
>  B) cheater
>  C) burglar
>  D) bandit

Comment: Maybe, 'thief' can fit in this context. It means she had stolen the copyright of others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What we're talking about here is the concept of **copyright theft**. This is the language that copyright holders' groups like to use about unauthorised copying of content, because they argue that it is stealing the content just like going to a shop and taking a CD (or whatever).

For that reason, the music industry would consider her a thief. Legal analysis varies, though it's still illegal (though not necessarily criminal) in all Berne Convention countries.

Answer (score 3):

Let's check what exactly mean cheater and thief.

According to the Oxford Dictionary

[**cheater**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/cheater)

> A person who acts dishonestly in order to gain an advantage.

[**thief**](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/thief)

> **A person who steals another person's property**, especially by stealth and **without using force** or threat of violence.

You have got to put yourself in the place of the Music Industry. What do you think they **care most**: you **being dishonest** or you **stealing their money**, not paying for their property? Is **honesty** a characteristic of the Music Industry or any other Industry?

I'd choose **thief**.